Riverpod: How to properly show error message under field on API error
I'm trying to create a verify OTP screen. The submit button will call the API to verify the OTP and on error I want to show error message under text field and clear the error when typing again. This is what I have done so far. It works first time but on further attempts to submit it keeps showing error under field since the controller is in error state. I feel like I'm missing a core point of doing this declaratively. I keep thinking imperatively. Is there a neat solution to this, Thanks.
// submit_controller.dart

class SubmitController extends AsyncNotifier<void> {

  @override
  FutureOr<void> build() {}

  Future<void> submit(String otp) async {
    state = const AsyncValue.loading();
    try {
// This will actually be a call to some repository method to verify otp.
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
      throw Exception('Invalid OTP');

    } catch (error, st) {
      state = AsyncError(error, st);
    }
  }
}

// main.dart

class HomePage extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  ...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final submit = ref.watch(submitControllerProvider);

    ref.listen(submitControllerProvider, (_, state) {
      final error = (state.error as Exception).toString();
      if (error == 'Exception: Invalid OTP') {
        isError = true;
        controller.clear();
      }
    });

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            TextField(
              enabled: !submit.isLoading,
              controller: controller,
              onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
                isError = false;
              }),
            ),
            isError
                ? const Text(
                    'Invalid OTP',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                  )
                : const SizedBox.shrink(),
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  ref.read(submitControllerProvider.notifier).submit(controller.text);
                },
                child: const Text('Submit')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


This looks like an ephemeral state, which Riverpod recommends not to use a provider to handle it. Pretty sure FormField got everything you need to handle such case.

@DhafinRayhan the submit method will make an api call which will return error if otp is invalid on which I want to show the error under the field. I've updated the question.
